# Spring Form Taglib and Custom Attributes from Item List

Tags: java, javascript, spring

I have a list of items, let's say `types`. I can display a `<select>` tag like so:

```
<form:select path="typeId" items="${types}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="typeId"/>
```

I would like to add the `description` property from the `Type` object to a `data-` attribute on the `<option>` tag for use with javascript.

This doesn't work, but just to provide an illustration:

```
<form:select path="typeId"/>
    <form:options items="${types}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="typeId" data-description="description"/>
</form:select>
```

How can I gain access to the `description` property to populate the `data-description` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own tag (may on base of form:options), but as far as I know there is no concept of extending tags. (sorry)

Comment: Kind of figured this would be the case but thought I would ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

data-description is not a valid attribute according to the [TLD](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.options), so any custom attribute will potentially throw exception.

You can:

1. Build select and options using standard tag lib using c:forEach OR
2. Repurpose existing unused attribute for JavaScript. May be "title" attribute?

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes